# Getting started with Git on live website server

Tags: git

I have a website and I currently use FTP to upload files. I now want to implement Git version control. I downloaded Git for Windows.

- Do I have to download the live website directory and then clone it `git clone /path/to/repository`?

Or

- Do I clone the live website directory directly using `git clone username@host:/path/to/repository`?

Do I need to install anything on the live server?

I already know about `git commit`, `git push origin` but difficulty understanding how to connect to live website server.

Comment: [Read a book first](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2).

Comment: `git init --bare` on the server, then add that folder as a remote on the client.

Comment: The production web server shouldn't really be involved in source control.  You'd maintain the source with Git (perhaps using a repository such as GitHub or BitBucket) and deploy to the web server separately from interacting with source control.

Comment: @David , so do i download the live website directory into a repository on GitHub and then use GitHub to deploy to the web server when i make changes to files?

Comment: @David note that sometimes the production server is also the web server. hashtag poor and paranoid.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you would want to do that, when you can have private Git repositories for free on [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org), or pay 10 bucks/month for private Git repositories on [GitHub](https://github.com).

--

But yes, if you really want to host on your own server, you will need to install a software on the server that will handle requests/responses - a Git server.

You can start by reading [Chapter 4 of the Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-on-the-Server).

You may also want to look at the products below (in no particular order), which you could install on your server.

- **GitHub Enterprise** - https://enterprise.github.com/home
- **BitBucket Server** (former Stash) - https://www.atlassian.com/software/bitbucket/server
- **GitLab** - https://about.gitlab.com
- **Bonobo** - https://bonobogitserver.com
- **GitBlit** - http://gitblit.com
- **Gitolite** - https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite
- **Others** - https://www.google.com/#q=git+server

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the hosting service that you are using. If you are using a shared hosting platform, it might cause some problem.
But yes you can deploy your website to a live server by installing git on your server.
Some Repo Hosting Providers : Beanstalk, Heroku, Github Pages(Static websites).